# if condition is true show block button else condition false show unblock button : Laravel, Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

If `$block->user_username` data empty show `block` button else run another if and else condition. But In foreach loop else not working `@else <a href="#0" class="cd-popup-trigger">Block2</a>` Please anyone help me.
Anyone know any other condition to do this things.

`@else <a href="#0" class="cd-popup-trigger">Block2</a> @endif` this else condition stuck only if condition is working. if this `@if(Auth::user()->name == $block->user_username && $user->username == $block->block_username)` condition is false code is not showing else condition.

```
 @foreach($blocked as $block)    
                   @if(empty($block->user_username ))
                     <a href="#0" class="cd-popup-trigger">Block1</a>

                   @else
                        @if(Auth::user()->username == $block->user_username and $user->username == $block->block_username)
                         <a href="#0" class="cd-popup-trigger">Unblock</a>
                         @else
                            <a href="#0" class="cd-popup-trigger">Block2</a>
                        @endif
                    @endif
            @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
@foreach($blocked as $block)    
  @if(!empty($block->user_username ))
    @if(Auth::user()->name == $block->user_username && $user->username == $block->block_username)
      <a href="#0" class="cd-popup-trigger">Unblock</a>
    @else
      <a href="#0" class="cd-popup-trigger">Block2</a>
    @endif
  @else
     <a href="#0" class="cd-popup-trigger">Block1</a> 
  @endif
@endforeach
```

i hope it will help

Comment: `@else
      <a href="#0" class="cd-popup-trigger">Block2</a>
    @endif` this else condition stuck only if condition is working. if this `@if(Auth::user()->name == $block->user_username && $user->username == $block->block_username)` condition is false code is not showing else condition